# Posting form response from react to node express with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am not very sure why this isn't working. I am trying to post from react to express using axios. I followed a tutorial on connecting react frontend to express server and it works for fetching data from server with a proxy. However, when I try to post data from react to the server, it does not work. I was prompted with two uncaught errors (cannot see them due to refresh) and then the page immediately refreshed with the form response posted to the url of the original react page instead of redirecting and posting to the server page with the form data.

[image: refreshed page]

client/package.json

```
{
  "name": "syllabus.io",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000/",
...
```

client/Login.js

```
import '../App.css';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function Login() {
    const [data, setData] = useState({
      email: "",
      password: ""
    });

    function handleLogin(e) {
      e.preventDafault();
      console.log(data.email, data.password);
      axios
      .post('http://localhost:8000/api/login-post', data)
      .then(() => console.log('Book Created'))
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      });
    }

    function handleInput(e) {
      const newData={...data};
      newData[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
      setData(newData);
    }
    

    return ( 
    <div id="login" className="login">
        <body>
          <h1 id="title">Login</h1>
          <div class="form">
            <form onSubmit={(e) => handleLogin(e)}>
            <input type="text" onChange={(e) => handleInput(e)} className="email" name="email" value={data.email} id="email" placeholder="Email"/> 
            <input type="text" onChange={(e) => handleInput(e)} className="password" name="password" value={data.password} id="password" placeholder="Password"/> 
            <input id="Login" className="Login" type="submit" value="Login"/> 
            </form>
          </div>
        </body>
      </div>
    );
  }
export default Login;
```

server/server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();



app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
    res.json({"user": ["userOne", "userTwo", "userThree"]})
})

app.post("/api/login-post", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.send("Success")
})

app.listen(8000, () => {console.log('Server started on port 8000...')})
```

Edit:
The error, after checking preserve log, is

[image: error]

Comment: Check the `Preserve logs` checkbox in the developer tools at the top there, so that the console doesn't get wiped when page refreshes. Then you can see errors and add them here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in e.preventDefault(); in handleLogin function thus your form is submitted without a payload. I hope this fixes it.